# TypeError: Cannot read property 'cookie' of undefined

Tags: mongodb, session, cookies, sails.js

When calling my `User.create` method in my Sails.js app,  I get the following error:

/Users/user/code/bt/tgein/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:779
      catch(err) { process.nextTick(function() { throw err}); }

Here is my User controller in its entirety.

```
User.create(req.params.all(), function userCreated(err, user) {
        // var userid = user.id;
        // console.log(userid);

        if(err) {
            console.log(err);

            req.session.flash = {
                err: err.ValidationError
            }

            return res.redirect('/user/loginDetails');
        }
        var oldDateObj = new Date();
        var newDateObj = new Date(oldDateObj.getTime() + 60000);
        req.session.cookie.expires = newDateObj;
        req.session.authenticated = true;
        console.log(req.session);
        // res.redirect('/user/profileSelection/?id=' + user.id);

        // Saves user data into session variable
        req.session.user = user;



        res.redirect('/user/profileSelection/');
    });
```

apparently the session value is undefined for the request. This seems symptomatic of something basic that isn't happening, but I don't know what that is.

Comment: My comment may or may not be useful for you. I don't really use sails.js but I was facing similar problem but I am using mongo with  mongoose and node js. My problem was there because the value I was querying wasn't there in exact format in schema. If this comment makes sense please let me know.

Comment: Ah. How do I ensure that i have the right schema or that your situation is happening in this case?

Answer (score 1):

`req.session.cookie` is not defined and you are trying to set a value to an undefined object.

```
var oldDateObj = new Date();
var newDateObj = new Date(oldDateObj.getTime() + 60000);
if(!req.session.cookie)
    req.session.cookie = {};
req.session.cookie.expires = newDateObj;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is not of session, as session is always retained/defined within an sails app. May be the issue exists, when you trying to save the data.

Comment: Ah. I think you are right. However, how do I go about seeing what is happening at the level of the data and the model?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I had the session store trying to go through the production adapter in my `sessions.js` on my local app, which caused the `req.session` to fail.